# Generar Random en Android y colocarlos en una caja de Texto

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo 3 archivos XML en mi recursos estos son :

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="nombres">
        <item>Ivan</item>
        <item>Jose</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
    ...
</resources>

<resources>
    <string-array name="apellidos">
        <item>More</item>
        <item>Flores</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
    ...
</resources>

<resources>
    <string-array name="correos">
        <item>gmail.com</item>
        <item>hotmail.com</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
    ...
</resources>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego tengo mi Actividad con el siguiente codigo:

```
public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView Nombre,Apellido,Correo;
    private Button Generar;
    //Sacamos los
    private String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombres);
    private String[] apellios = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.apellidos);
    private String[] correo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.correos);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
        //Seteamos las Cajas de Texto
        Nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        Apellido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
        Correo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCorreo);
        Generar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar);
        //Ponemos en Modo de Escucha al Boton
        findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Mi Problema surge de como generar un randon de estos 3 XML y ponerlo en una caja de texto.

Este es mi modelo del aplicativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer es un autocomplete?

Comment: @DesarrolladorAndroidJr. Que al momento de darle en el boton Generar me coloque cualquiern nombre del String y en apellidos igual solo que nombre sera un nombre y en Apellidos 2, ayuda porfa recien estoy empezando en android :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView Nombre,Apellido,Correo;
    private Button Generar;
    //Sacamos los
    private String[] names;// = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombres);
    private String[] apellios;// = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.apellidos);
    private String[] correo;// = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.correos);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombres);
        apellios = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.apellidos);
        correo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.correos);
        //Seteamos las Cajas de Texto
        Nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        Apellido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);
        Correo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCorreo);
        Generar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar);
        //Ponemos en Modo de Escucha al Boton
        findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (R.id.btnGenerar==v.getId())
        {
            Nombre.setText(ObtieneRandom(names));
            Apellido.setText(ObtieneRandom(apellios));
            Correo.setText(ObtieneRandom(correo));
        }
    }
    public String ObtieneRandom(String [] array)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return array[random.nextInt(array.length-1)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Remplaza MainActivity  por el nombre de tu clase

Comment: Gracias :'), espero mi voto positivo y que en otra oportunidad me vuelvas a salvar :c

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un metodo que se encargue de obtener los valores aleatoriamente que reciba como parametro un **array** (en este caso seran los valores definidos en **array.xml** o **strings.xml** ).

Instancias en **random** para obtener valores aleatorios.

Obtienes un valor de tu **array** utilizando el **random**, obteniendo unicamente ***enteros*** e indicas el valor **maximo** a obtener que sera el tamaño de tu **array-1**, recordemos que un array comienza desde **0** por eso sera el **total-1** y retornas el valor seleccionado

```
    public String ObtieneRandom(String [] array)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return array[random.nextInt(array.length-1)];
    }
```

Para asignar el valor a tu **EditText** o **TextView** unicamente realizas una llamada al metodo enviando como parametro tu **array** *con los valores definidos*

```
Nombre.setText(ObtieneRandom(names));
Apellido.setText(ObtieneRandom(apellios));
Correo.setText(ObtieneRandom(correo));
```

Comment: muchas gracias, @DesarrolladorAndroidJr por tu respuesta, mis array las tengo en la carpeta value de los recursos estos se llaman "Nombres.xml","Apellidos.xml","Correos.xml", entonces tu respuesta esque haga una clases llamada ObtieneRandom (osea cree esa clase), y luego de ahi llame a los string, por fa si puedes integrarlo con mi codigo ayudame :c

Comment: Es un metodo y no una clase.